# Extracting data embedded in an 8-bit array into different size array

Tags: c, bit, data-conversion, i2c

I am working on a project which receives a series of parameters condensed into an 8 bit array. These parameters can come in varying sizes, but are always sent in an 8 bit array. The goal is to extract these parameters into an array the size of the largest sized parameter (which is already known beforehand).

---

For example, there could be two 4 bit parameters stored in the first index of the parameter array, then one 8 bit parameter, then one 16 bit parameter. The goal would then be to place each parameter separately in a 16 bit array of length 4, where extra space are just 0's. I am struggling finding a way to do this efficiently, especially since the i2c array could potentially have multiple parameters embedded within one byte of the array. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

---

To better illustrate this, take our 8-bit data array = [0011 1011, 0110 1111] and take our parameter lengths to be = [2, 2, 4, 8]. Then, I would want the result array to appear as [0000 00**00**, 0000 00**11**, 0000 **1011**, **0110 1111**]. The bold numbers indicate the bits taken from the data array.

Comment: How will you know which parameter is of which length(4, 8 16 bits) just by looking at the data?

Comment: @SparKot: He knows. He certainly has a bunch of different structures and wants to know the general principle.

Comment: @SparKot, all of the parameters are known from obtainable documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this kind of problem before by simply considering the received array of bytes as a bit flow.

So it's quite easy to read 3 bits, then 7 bits, then 10 bits, then 2 bits, etc. until the end of the buffer.

You simply need to keep an index to the current bit:

```cpp
struct bitflow {
  unsigned char* data ; // Received data
  size_t datasize ; // Data size, in bytes.
  size_t pc ;  // Current bit pointer, initialize it to zero.
}
```

To get the next bit (0/1=bit, -1=error):

```cpp
int getnextbit (struct bitflow* b) {
  // Check if we didn't already reached the end of buffer.
  // "pc" must be stricly below (classic C indexes) than the number of bytes (datasize) multiplied by 8 (number of bits per byte).
  // A shift of 3 ranks to the left is the same as multiplying by 8, but is faster and will be faster even without any enabled optimization from compiler.
  if (pc>=(datasize<<3))
    return -1 ;
  // Where is the bit:
  // - Targeted byte is the integer part of "pc/8". Again, a shift to accelerate that.
  // - Targeted bit is the remainder of "pc/8". A binary mask with 7 do the same, again faster than a modulo even without optimizations.
  // We then shift a bit (1) to the position of the remainder, and with a bitwise "AND", we extract the bit.
  // If the result is zero, the bit wasn't set, we return zero.
  // If non-zero (equal to (1<<((b->pc) & 7)), in fact), we return "1".
  int result = (((b->data[(b->pc)>>3]) & (1<<((b->pc) & 7))) ? 1 : 0) ;
  // We extracted a bit, so we increment the pointer to next bit.
  b->pc++ ;
  return result ;
}
```

To get the next N bits (max. 31 bits, >=0 = OK, <0=error):

```cpp
// l2m==0: read from LSB to MSB, otherwise, read from MSB to LSB.
int getnextbits (struct bitflow* b, int nbbits, int l2m) {
  if ((nbbits<0) || (nbbits>31))
    return -2 ;
  if ((pc+nbbits)>=(datasize<<3))
    return -1 ;
  int result = 0 ;
  size_t j=b->pc ;
// Alternatives for endianness (depends on both CPU used and I2C data format, read both datasheets and/or simply test):
  if (l2m) {
    // 1st read bit is LSB (least significant bit), last read bit is MSB (most significant bit).
    for (int i=0 ; i<nbbits ; i++, j++)
      result |= (((b->data[j>>3]) & (1<<(j & 7))) ? (1<<i) : 0) ;
  } else {
    // 1st read bit is MSB, last read bit is LSB.
    for (int i=(nbbits-1) ; i>=0 ; i--, j++)
      result |= (((b->data[j>>3]) & (1<<(j & 7))) ? (1<<i) : 0) ;
  }
  b->pc += nbbits ;
  return result ;
}
```

This last function can be **heavily** optimized by getting directly all possible remaining bits of the current byte, if `nbbits` (or the number of bits still to extract) is greater or equal to the number of bits left in the current byte. But it shouldn't be needed if you don't have a huge load of data, which is quite unlikely if you get these data from I²C.

Endianness can complexify things a bit, but it's not impossible to solve - I usually do the endianness swap directly at reception when needed.

Finally, you can read data this way:

```cpp
// Considering structure is filled by reception routine.
struct bitflow b = getdatafromi2c() ;
// Number of bits for each consecutive element.
int format[10] = { 4, 4, 2, 2, 4, 16, 10, 2, 1, 1 } ;
unsigned short int result[10] ;
for (int i=0 ; i<10 ; i++ ) {
  int v = getnextbits(&b, format[i]) ;
  if (v<0) {
    // Error handling
    ....
  }
  result[i] = (unsigned short int)v ;
}
// Use result array normally from now.
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I was also thinking along the lines of a bitstream but wasn't quite sure how to go about implementing it. Still need to get more comfortable with some bit operations

Comment: If you don't mind, could you explain the first three lines of getnextBit()?

Comment: @mattoro No problem. I edited my answer and added comments to `getnextbit`. Tell me if it isn't enough.

Comment: That is perfect, thank you very much

Comment: So reading through the code, it seems that the getnextbits function  always return the bits in reverse order (I assume due to endianness?). If so, would a quick fix just to be to remove the first line in the for loop, and then shift the second line left by i?

Comment: @mattoro Answer edited, you can now do both. More reusability this way.

Comment: Thanks again! Unfortunately, the current code does not work for the goal at hand, but this is a great starting point! (for example, take data = [0x3b, 0x8f] and format = [2, 2, 4, 8]. This returns result = [3, 2, 3, 8f] which is incorrect. That is, the current algorithm parses 'b' in half first instead of '3', and the order in which it splits 'b' is also backward)

Comment: for simplicity sake, I added an example to my post to better illustrate what I meant.

Answer (score -1):

```
    uint8_t input_array[4];
    uint16_t output_array[4];

    // I have to make an assumption that the two fours are filled little-endian. If it's wrong, it's wrong.
    // You will generally have this problem whenever parameters span bytes. You have to know.
    output_array[0] = input_array[0] & 0xF;
    output_array[1] = input_array[0] >> 4;
    output_array[2] = input_array[1];
    // Similar story here. I assume that input_array's bytes are little endian.
    // You normally find bit-endian and byte-endian are the same but a contrary system could exist.
    output_array[3] = input_array[2] | (input_array[3] << 8);
```

In the old days people used to do this with structs. Somebody's going to come by and tell me this is undefined, etc; it doesn't really matter. A compiler that emits terrible code for the above emits good code for the below. It's the modern optimizing compilers that an figure the most efficient way for the above that will mess up the below. This has all kinds of alignment and endian assumptions built into it; however where it works, it works well. Where it doesn't work it's undefined.

```
     union u {
         uint8_t input_array[4];
         struct input {
             unsigned char param0 : 4;
             unsigned char param1 : 4;
             unsigned char param2 : 8;
             unsigned char param3 : 6;
         }
     } input_form;

    union input_form input;
    uint16_t output_array[4];
    output_array[0] = input.input.param0;
    output_array[1] = input.input.param1;
    output_array[2] = input.input.param2;
    output_array[3] = input.input.param3;
```

Comment: thanks for the input! I can see how this solves the problem for my example, but I'm having a hard time seeing how to generalize this to all kinds of possible input arrays.

Comment: @mattoro: I would write it inline for each input array.